# Clearing data on a stolen iphone 5s when my phone has no network?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, security, privacy

My phone has recently been stolen, I immediately went to my network provider and cancelled my network on the handset, I then found out I could remotely erase all data on the handset however it says once the phone is connected to the internet? Is it possible to clear all the data (messages, pictures, videos) when the phone does not have a signal and is not connected to the internet?

Comment: If your network will reactivate your sim in the phone, and it is still in the phone, otherwise refer to grgarside response.

Answer (score 3):

No, the iPhone must have some form of internet connectivity to receive the signal to erase.

Since you have disabled the phone's mobile internet, the only way it will receive the signal is if **another SIM card** is put in the phone which would enable the data, or it is **connected to a Wi-Fi network**.